# Can't enter different values with a scanner in a object in an array

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, arraylist

I need to be able to enter different value from a scanner in the same object in an array...My array is :

```
public static ArrayList<Case> monArrayCase = new ArrayList<Case>();
```

Comment: I have a feeling you are using the `static` keyword incorrectly. When a variable is `static` there is only ever 1 of them for an entire class. If you change it for one instance, you change it for all of them.

Comment: Post the relevant code to replicate the problem. Also, please read about `static` keyword in Java.

Comment: Yeah I have a problem each time I try to change to another thing than static eclipse write me this : Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field monArrayCase

Comment: You have to create a new `Case` instance for every set of values you're scanning! Add these instances to your array list then.

Comment: where do you use `Scanner` ?

Comment: Ive edited my main post to show you my main scanner method

Answer (score 2):

One typical reason for values in different elements of a List being the same is that

```
Case case = new Case();
```

is called once. Then, fields of case are set using

```
case.setLigne(x);
case.setColone(y);
case.setValeur(z);
```

Repeated

```
list.add( Case.case );
```

will add entries, but they'll all refer to the same object, Case.case, and its values depend on the last setter calls.

Seeing that Case.case is a static variable, this is quite likely to be the case here, too.

To fix, call the constructor repeatedly, even for the static object Case.case.

```
while( ... ){ // there is another Case to do
   // read values for ligne, colone, valeur
   Case.case = new Case( ligne. colone, valeur );
   monArrayCase.add(Case.case1);
}
```

Of course, Case.case can be replaced by a local object

```
   Case nextCase = new Case(...);
```

Or, using your code (removing some useless complications and truncating long strings):

```
public void fairePlacementTest2() {
    System.out.println("Bonjours,...");
    System.out.println("Veuillez...");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int ligne = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Veuillez...");
    int colone = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Veuillez...");
    int valeur = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");

    monArrayCase.add(new Case( ligne, colone, valeur ) );
}
```

**Later**

Here a complete solution for entering the data:

```
public class Case {
    private int ligne;
    private int colone;
    private int valeur;
    public Case( int ligne, int colone, int valeur ){
        this.ligne = ligne;
        this.colone = colone;
        this.valeur = valeur;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "(" + ligne + "," + colone + ")=" + valeur;
    }
}

import java.util.*;
public class Grid {
    private List<Case> cases = new ArrayList<>();

    public void placement(){
        System.out.println("Bonjours,...");
        System.out.println("Veuillez... terminez avec zero!");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while( true ){
            int ligne = scanner.nextInt();
            if( ligne == 0 ) break;
            int colone = scanner.nextInt();
            int valeur = scanner.nextInt();
            cases.add(new Case( ligne, colone, valeur ) );
        }
    }

    public List<Case> getCases(){
        return cases;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        Grid g = new Grid();
        g.placement();
        for( Case c: g.getCases() ){
             System.out.println( c );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "call the constructor repeatedly"?

Comment: "Repeatedly" = "more than once" = "plus que one fois"

Comment: Haha I know what repeatedly mean in english thank but I mean how can I call the constructor repeatedly?

Comment: Put another way, call `case = new Case()` before you call the three setters each time.  Don't just construct a single Case object and set (overwrite) its values each time; you want a new Case object for each trio of ligne, colone, and valeur you read.

Comment: OK, it is indeed as I thought. See my addition - make sure to create a **new Case(l,c,v)** for each user input of a triple.

Comment: Ive try what you said but the result is the same: [Ligne :5, Colone:6, Valeur:7||, Ligne :5, Colone:6, Valeur:7||]

Comment: Maybe that because my arraylist is static?As I have tried it with standard variable...Here my arraylist looklike : public static ArrayList<Case> monArrayCase = new ArrayList<Case>();

Comment: "make sure to create a new Case(l,c,v) for each user input of a triple" do you think i can only call the method fairePlacementTest2() each time in another to do the trick or it will not work?

Comment: You can call fairePlacementTest2() repeatedly (omitting the "Bonjour") from elsewhere *or* you can wrap a loop around the code after "Bonjour" so that you have call it only once, to get all Sudoku fields the user wants to enter. It does not matter - as long each triplet ends up in another **new Case(...)**. C'ést ça, vraiment!

Comment: Of course it works. See a complete set of 2 classes. Note that a single 0 followed by "return" terminates.